# sonar-scanner doesn't see *.jar file

Tags: java, unix, sonarqube

I've installed `sonarqube` and it works on `localhost:9000` Sonar scanner doesn't work.

**I've tried** to change `sonar-scanner-cli-4.0.0.1744.jar` file location. But it doesn't work anyway.

```
sonar-scanner
File does not exist: /usr/local/lib/sonar-scanner-cli-4.0.0.1744.jar
'/usr/local' does not point to a valid installation directory: /usr/local
```

I expect to run `sonar scanner`, and I think that I need to change default `sonar-scanner` `sonar-scanner-cli-4.0.0.1744.jar` location.

Comment: Did u get chance to look into  setting up the [Sonarqube-scanner](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-ensure-code-quality-with-sonarqube-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Yes, I did, but it ask for /usr/local/lib not /opt/sonnarscanner